# AWS SES with Google Apps MX Record Record Delete Necessary?

Tags: amazon-web-services, mx-record, g-suite, amazon-ses

I don't have much knowledge, so before proceeding on something too fast, I'd like some help on AWS and Gsuite MX records.

I have a domain example.com, which is registered on Godaddy, but i have its DNS set up to use it with Route53, since Im hosting the site on AWS and using a variety of their services, such as SES which the bulk email service for my website's transactional email such as notifications.

Previously did not have it set up with a mail server like Gsuite or anything, since no emailing was being done with the example.com domain. The only Email work being done is Amazon AWS's SES service at the moment. *I know want to be able to send and receive emails with same domain name, and also keep SES running with my website normally.*

I added example.com to Google Apps domains, and already verified by adding CNAME records through Route53's DNS management tool. Google's Gsuite needs me to add MX record to the domain on the DNS tool.

The issue is the following:
I already have MX records created on route 53 for smtp bulk emailing with this MX record: 10 inbound-smtp.us-west-2.amazonaws.com

Google's G suite's instructions say I have to delete all present MX records to be able to add their MX records. If I delete this MX record, it will disable my SES service from Amazon.

Question:
Can I add google's MX records and leave the current one supporting SES as well into route 53, without affecting each other and both services work fine? (Gsuite + SES related MX records together?

Answer (score 1):

If you are only using SES for outbound, then delete the SES MX record and use the Google records.  MX only affects *inbound* mail.

You can't use both on the exact same domain name because the MX records dictate where all mail addressed to any user at the domain name is to route.  The routing cannot be more granular than that.

In the future, if you need inbound SES, you can create a subdomain and use that for your inbound addresses, with a new MX for the subdomain pointing to SES.